# Letter T in date conversion to Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, varchar

I saw a post similar to this one that had a solution that would be more of a work around to this issue than a solution.

We are moving SQL from 2008 to 2012.  There was a process already in place that cannot be changed.  Basically the application takes queries stored in the DB runs the queries on a schedule and then in some cases returns the results and sends them in an HTML formatted email.

The problem is that the current application when sending an email using SQL 2008 returns the date formatted as "mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss AM" but using the exact same code on the 2012 server we get "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.000" with military time and a "T" in the middle of the date and time.

The solution I saw in the other post said to format the date like this in the query:

```
convert(nvarchar, start_date, 121) As [start_date]
```

Which works...but this would require changes to all of the hundreds of queries that are currently stored in the data.  It is working in the current production environment with SQL 2008...but the new app using SQL 2012 changes the date format.  On another site I saw someone with a similar issue, but they were using 2008 and the issue happened while still in 2008.  No real resolution there either.

Is there a setting perhaps that we may be overlooking?  The client does not want us to change the code unless we absolutely have to.

So an example query stored in the DB would be:

```
SELECT start_date FROM base_table
```

A stored procedure then runs the query and returns the results as XML

```
SET @sql = query + " FOR XML RAW ";
EXEC(@sql);
```

which are stored in a varchar(max) field in the data.

Another stored procedure takes the XML from that field and puts HTML tags around the XML data:

```
'<TABLE>' + XML + '</TABLE>'
```

Then sends the email using dbmail.

Results in the email for SQL2008 would be:

### start_date

10/15/2004 1:00 PM

10/21/2005 5:25 PM

Results in the email for SQL 2012 would be:

### start_date

2004-10-15T13:00:00.000

2005-21-21T17:25:00.000

Convoluted I know...but that's what we have to work with.

Thanks

Comment: What does the pplication use to connect to SQL Server? What query does it run? Please also post relevant fields' definitions.

Comment: Updated the post...hopefully a little more clear.  But the main question is...why would it be different on the new server?  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the default date format with the set dateformat command:

> SET DATEFORMAT format
>
> Valid formats: mdy, dmy, ymd, ydm, myd, dym